# phpDocumentor - changing a template

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I am using phpDocumentor from http://phpdoc.org.

Trying to change the template "responsive-twig" drives me nuts.
Any changes I make to

```
/usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/data/templates/responsive-twig/layout.html.twig
```

are fully ignored.
However, if I rename the file and run phpdoc, I get the error that this file could not be found.
I then emptied this file (0 Bytes) - and the phpdoc command runs fine, producing exactly the same output as with the original file.

Between all attempts, I always deleted the whole output directory to make sure there ist no caching involved.

I do not understand, how and where the templates get their info from and documentation about templates is not available on the website of phpDocumentor. Searching all over google did not help either.

Any hints? I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: I experienced the same thing! I was about to go mad! Could not find *anything* about caching in the documentation. Now I found the caching location on Windows: `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\phpdoc-twig-cache`. The better option is to use the `twig-debug` parameter though.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. When using a twig based template the generated files seem to be cached in the tmp folder of your system, so caching IS involved even if you're deleting the whole output directory every time. As written [here](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1138) you should be able to solve this problem by clearing the tmp folder of your system every time you make changes.

Though, this solution did not work for me, clearing the tmp folder did not cause changes. So I added the following line of code to the Twig.php file in the function addExtensionsFromTemplateConfiguration to stop twig from caching:

```
$twigEnvironment->enableAutoReload();
```

Ugly but effective.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `twig-debug` parameter to your `template.xml` file:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter key="twig-debug">true</parameter>
</parameters>
```

See details here: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1114